# Order by in stuff part of pivot query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

I want to sort the dates in asc order with the stuff part of pivot query.

**Example**:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT  distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(column_date)--(column_date)
              FROM #temp 
              order by column_date /* Error occured here*/
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')
PRINT(@cols)
```

Getting error for above script near by order by clause.

**Error Details**:

```
Msg 145, Level 15, State 1, Line 4  
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

You can Use Group by `column_date` it will return distinct dates

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT    ',' + QUOTENAME(column_date)--(column_date)
              FROM #temp 
              GROUP BY column_date
              order by column_date /* Error occured here*/
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')
PRINT(@cols)
```

Answer (score 2):

I dono why you are using `order by` without `Top clause`. try this..

```
SELECT @cols = ',' + column_date
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT Quotename(column_date) column_date
        FROM   #temp) A
ORDER  BY column_date

SELECT @cols = RIGHT(@cols, Len(@cols) - 1)
```